# Open with menu is missing while opening a .tex file

Tags: registry

I am using *MikTex 2.9* and *TexStudio* for Latex writing in my PC with **Windows 7**. I am facing this problem of opening a **.tex** file (latex file) by a double click with the following error "This file does not have a program associated with it for performing this action. Please instal a program or, if one is already installed, create an association in the Default Programs Control panel". But the program TexStudio is already installed in my PC. Also when I am opening *TexStudio* and then open the **.tex** file from File menu---> Open, then it is opening and working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call the context menu in Explorer, "Open with...", then select your preferable editor, and check up the box "Use this choice for all files of such type" in explorer dialog.